# JQuery: "SyntaxError: Unrecognized expression" - Despite string being escaped

Tags: jquery, syntax, escaping, selector

Why is it, that if I take an escaped string, put it in a variable and use it as a jquery selector I get that error, but if I take the exact same string, use it directly as a selector (without storing it in a variable first) it works just fine?

Here's a picture:

[image: Chrome Dev Console Ouput]

The best and cleanest solution would be to permit the input of any meta characters as IDs. But that'd be a huge change in another part of the software and would probably give us many issues regarding downward compatibility.

Comment: The code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pg7o05bx/. As an aside from the problem, what element are you expecting `(1)` to match?

Comment: The id of the element I want to match is "dialog_Page (1)".

Comment: That's not a valid `id` attribute; they cannot contain spaces.

Comment: If you use attribute selector it would work but still it is invalid ID attribute... `'[id="dialog_Page (1)"]'`

Comment: *"works just fine"* - it returns an empty array, so it's not finding your element, so it's not working.

Comment: That it didn't return anything is okay. If it returns nothing, I load the element into the DOM. So next time it will return the correct element.

And thanks for the comments, I will look into that.